# Rails 3: How to add a method to the Gem model without changing the Gem source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, overriding

```
version : Rails 3.2.22.2
```

I'm using the Impressionist gem to track user activity: 
https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist

This gives me `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error`.
I want to override the `Impression` module from the gem to use `attr_accessible`.

I tried 2 things:

1: Create an `impression.rb` file under `app/models`

```
class Impression
  def hello
    "hello world"
  end
end
```

In `initializer/impression.rb`,

```
require 'impression'
```

when I try the following on console:

```
a = Impression.first
a.hello
```

I get method not found error.

2: I added the code in the `initializezs/impression.rb` file:

```
Impression.class_eval do
    def hi
        puts 'you got me!'
    end
end
```

and I still got the same error as in point 1.

How can I effectively override the model from the gem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did the following modification to make my code work. Under initializers I create a file -> `initializer/my_monkey_patch.rb` with following code

```
class Impression < ActiveRecord::Base
        attr_accessible :impressionable_type, :impressionable_id, :controller_name, :action_name, :user_id, :request_hash, :session_hash, :ip_address, :referrer

        def hello
            "hello WORLD!"
        end
end
```

Thank you @Mohammad Shahadat Hossain for all your help

Comment: Its my pleasure you have found the solution. It is great.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to go with 2 method. But you have see if you method already in a class. Then for overriding it you need to use in your `model/impression_decorator.rb`.

```
Impression.class_eval do
  attr_accessor  :something

  def hi
    puts 'you got me! #{someting}'
  end
end
```

Comment: The original model/impression.rb class in the Gem has no methods at all. I want to add to that model attr_accessible :some_existing_field and some method.

Comment: Then you can do something like above. `Impression.class_eval` thats all you  have to use. Use any method and attr_accessor as possible.

Comment: I created model/impression_decorator.rb file and added the code you mentioned to it. Nothing in the initializer. When i restart the app, I still cannot access the 'hi' method

Comment: How you are accessing it?

Comment: From the rails console-> a = Impression.first  a.hi

Comment: `a = Impression.new` then `a.hi`. You have to create a object of the class first to access its method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107260/discussion-between-kavitac-and-mohammad-shahadat-hossain).

Comment: This worked for me trying to add some methods to a model defined in a gem.  Thanks!